# What is the step in this proof "because $\omega$ is closed"?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working through this proof of the Poincare lemma [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&lpg=PA296&ots=j-ImO3ZbTX&dq=poincare%20lemma%20proof%20star-shaped&pg=PA296#v=onepage&q=poincare%20lemma%20proof%20star-shaped&f=false) but I don't understand one step.

First, there is the following equation

$$ {\partial \over \partial x^j} f(x) = \int_0^1 \left (t {\partial \omega_i (tx)\over \partial x^j} x^i + \omega_j (tx) \right) dt $$

> But should this be  $$ {\partial \over \partial x^j} f(x) = \int_0^1
>  \left ( {\partial \omega_i (tx)\over \partial x^j} x^i +
>  \omega_j (tx) \right) dt $$? The $x$ inside $\omega_i$ is a constant and $\omega_i$ is not a function of $x^j$ unless $j=i$, no?

Although he previously used Einstien notation I believe that the sum here actually disappears but I don't see why.

Then he goes on to say that because $\omega$ is closed,

$$ {\partial \over \partial x^j} f(x) = \int_0^1 \left (t {\partial \omega_i (tx)\over \partial x^j} x^i + \omega_j (tx) \right) dt = \int_0^1 {d\over dt}(t \omega_j(tx)) dt$$

> But $\omega$ closed means $d\omega = 0$ and I don't see why this would
>   make a ${d\over dt}$ appear. Please could someone elaborate for me?

Answer (score 2):

Not using Einstein summation convention:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
t \omega_j(tx)
\right)
&=
\left(
\frac{d}{dt}
t \right)
\omega_j(tx)
+
t 
\left(
\frac{d}{dt}
 \omega_j(tx)
\right) \\
&=
\omega_j(tx)
+
\left(
\sum_i
t \frac{\partial \omega_j}{\partial x^i}(tx)
\frac{d(t x^i)}{dt}
\right)
\\
&=
\omega_j(tx)
+
\left(
\sum_i
t \frac{\partial \omega_j}{\partial x^i}(tx)
\,
x^i
\right)
\\
&=
\omega_j(tx)
+
\left(
\sum_i
t \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j}(tx)
\,
x^i
\right)
\end{align}

where I used the closedness of $\omega$ (no rotation) in the last step.

Comment: @WillieWong How does $\partial \omega_{j}/ \partial x_i = \partial\omega_i / \partial x_j$ follow from $d\omega = 0$?

Comment: @a.student see proposition 11.45 on page 295.

Comment: oh... I think I'm starting to understand... If $n=3$ and  $\omega = \omega_x dx + \omega_y dy + \omega_z dz$ then  $$ d\omega = {d\over dy}\omega_x dy \wedge dx+ {d\over dz}\omega_x dz \wedge dx + {d\over dx}\omega_y dx \wedge dy + {d\over dz}\omega_y dz \wedge dy + {d\over d x} \omega_z dx \wedge dz + {d\over d y} \omega_z dy \wedge dz=0$$
implies $$ {d\over dy } \omega_x = {d\over dx}\omega_y$$ etc.

Comment: Can you write the sums please? Einstein notation doesn't make things clear. If you're summing then it would be $n \omega_j(tx)$ since we're summing over $i$, right?

Comment: Thank you for changing it. But I still don't see how $${\partial \over \partial x^j}  \omega_i(tx) x^i $$ is equal to 

$$ t {\partial \omega_i (tx)\over \partial x^j} x^i  $$ 
The $x$ inside $\omega_i$ is not a variable, it's a constant. What am I missing?

Comment: The question here is what is $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\omega_i(tx)\right)x^i$$

Comment: It could be a scaling issue like $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \omega_i(tx) = t \frac{\partial}{\partial(tx_j)}\omega_i(tx) = t \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j}(tx)$$ My understanding of the notation $\omega_i(v)$ is too vague. I lack the book.